# Trouble with Xbox Series S, MSI Pro MP241X Monitor, and Dell WD15 Docking Station Setup

Tags: technical-issues, monitor, xbox-series-x-series-s

I'm facing an issue with my current gaming setup, and I'm hoping to get some guidance on resolving it. Here's the rundown:

I have an Xbox Series X connected to an MSI Pro MP241X monitor through a Dell WD15 docking station. The Xbox is connected to the docking station via HDMI, and the docking station is connected to the monitor using a VGA cable.

The primary reason for this configuration is that the monitor's built-in audio is not functioning. Instead, I'm attempting to route the audio through a portable speaker connected to the docking station's 3.5mm headphone jack.

Unfortunately, this setup isn't working (the monitor shows no output). I'm curious to know if there's a logical issue with this configuration or if there are any troubleshooting steps I can take to make it work.